# Why is list multiplication so fast?

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

When creating a list, I thought comprehension is recommended whenever possible as it is fastest. But lo and behold.

```
In [1]: %timeit -n1000 [0]*1000000
1000 loops, best of 3: 2.3 ms per loop

In [2]: %timeit -n1000 [0 for _ in range(1000000)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 27.1 ms per loop

In [3]: a = np.zeros(1000000, dtype=int)

In [4]: %timeit -n1000 a.tolist()
1000 loops, best of 3: 7.93 ms per loop
```

Even `numpy.ndarray.tolist` can't keep up with multiplication. Why is that?

Comment: #2 actually runs a python loop, while #1 is completely interpreted without any python loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#dis.dis) module is useful for comparing the first two methods.

```
def list_mult():
    return [0]*1000000

dis.dis(list_mult)
#  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
#              3 BUILD_LIST               1
#              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (1000000)
#              9 BINARY_MULTIPLY     
#             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

Here, the `BINARY_MULTIPLY` instruction is used. On the other hand...

```
def list_range():
    return [0 for _ in range(1000000)]

dis.dis(list_range)
# 2           0 BUILD_LIST               0
#             3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
#             6 LOAD_CONST               1 (1000000)
#             9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
#            12 GET_ITER            
#       >>   13 FOR_ITER                12 (to 28)
#            16 STORE_FAST               0 (_)
#            19 LOAD_CONST               2 (0)
#            22 LIST_APPEND              2
#            25 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
#       >>   28 RETURN_VALUE
```

This function explicitly constructs a loop, and then loads 0 and appends it to the working list in each iteration. This is going to be a lot slower.

It should be noted that ***these two construction methods are not equivalent***, particularly when the value inside the list is mutable. For example, `[object()] * 10` will give you a list of 10 of the same object, while `[object() for _ in range(10)]` will give you a list of 10 distinct objects.

Regarding the `numpy` example, this operation is kind of the worst-case for `numpy`. There is a lot of overhead in constructing and converting `numpy` arrays so that the vectorized operations can be fast (as noted in the comments).

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, python can create a list with all the zeroes referring to the same `id`. This works great since primitives are *literal*, but it wouldn't work as expected if you're passing an object. In that case, every element would actually be a reference to the same object.

In the `range` case, there are function calls being made, so that creates more overhead.