# Why there is a significant difference in python3 in-line array initialization vs use of * operator?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

After multiple testing I have realized that

```
a = 1000
b = 2000
test = [ [ 0 for i in range(a) ] for j in range(b) ]
```

takes more time as compared to

```
a = 1000
b = 2000
test = [ [0] * a for i in range(b) ]
```

in python3.
Anyone can explain why is that?
Or am I missing something here?

Comment: not sure but could be related to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37706477/why-is-list-multiplication-so-fast  -> It should be noted that these two construction methods are not equivalent, particularly when the value inside the list is mutable. For example, [object()] * 10 will give you a list of 10 of the same object, while [object() for _ in range(10)] will give you a list of 10 distinct objects.

Comment: I think yeah, in a way it answers my question, thanks @pippo1980